# explicit operator + in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i'm just playing with the + operator & i cannot figure out how to declare it and use it 'explicitly' 
please help the code is below :

```
class compex{

    int real;
    int img;

public:
    compex();
    compex(int,int);
    compex& explicit operator + (const compex& P1)
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,const compex& R);
};
```

and the implementation of the operator is:

```
  compex& compex :: operator + (const compex& P1)
 {
    this->real += P1.real;
   this->img += P1.img;
   return *this;
 }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? If so what error? Or is there something else you are struggling with?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Your code has several problem, please explain what you mean by 'explicit' and what exact problem you have.

Comment: The `+` operator is never used implicitly.  It's automatically explicit.  Also, the code you wrote implements `+=`, not `+`.

Comment: Ah c'mon - it's not too hard to guess OP just wants to prevent implicit conversions when using operator+.

Comment: @DrewDormann: That's not true. Things will implicitly convert to it, if conversions are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make (these) operators `explicit` (only conversion operators can be made explicit in C++11). And you don't need to. Simply avoid explicit conversions to your type, by:

- not defining conversion operators for other types, and..
- marking all constructors of complex that can be called with one parameter `explicit`.

That way, you can effectively only call `operator+` with types that are already `complex`.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ also allows conversion operators as global functions and as members functions in the "from" type.  Forbidding conversions to `complex` is tricky, and only trickier when trying to enforce it only for `operator +`.

Comment: It isn't just for constructors with one parameter: http://liveworkspace.org/code/30a0gl%240

Comment: @chris: good point, still missing a lot of C++11 knowledge :) I'll add that.

Comment: @Drew: I never knew you can have conversion operators as global functions. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The explicit keyword is only useful on constructors with one parameter. It will stop the compiler from using that constructor for conversions. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish by making your + operator explicit. :)

Comment: Minor detail: explicit can also be used on constructors that have more than one parameter if the others have default values, i.e. when it can be called as if it had only one parameter.

Comment: Also, conversion operators can be made explicit in addition to conversion constructors.

Comment: @MooingDuck - yes, but only with C++11. In C++03 conversion operators could not be marked explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `explicit` converting function, you will have to write one just for that purpose (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)) (but it will only work with one parameter).

As for your `operator+(...)`, just remove `explicit` and it should work.

```
Compex c1(1,2);
Compex c2(3,12);
Compex c3 = c1 + c2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent types from implicitly converting to `compex` when using `operator +`, you can take advantage of template parameters.

Template parameters are not directly subject to type conversion rules.

```
class compex{
    template<class C, 
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<C,complex>::value>::type >  
    compex& operator + (const C& P1)
    {
       // Your code
    }
};
```